# YamlDotNet - How to deserialize multiple different document which is together?

Tags: yamldotnet

Searched online for a solution but didn't get it. Is there anyone for help!

I want to deserialize following YAML documents. The problem is each document is in the different structure. Is there anyway?

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!1001 &100100000
Prefab:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 1
  serializedVersion: 2
--- !u!1 &1441507915387346
GameObject:
  m_Component:
  - component: {fileID: 4226623389636744}
  m_Layer: 0
  m_Name: Pikachu
```